# Drag and Drop Sortable

Tags: drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I just want to know where can I place some function in my drag and drop. I tried using alert messages to know where the event takes place but it's not executing any of my alert boxes. I put alert boxes in comment, those are places i used to place it but nothing happens. My drag and drop works but it cant fire alert box. I dont know what is wrong. Help me. Thanks.

```
var adjustment;
$(function () {
    $("#container1, #container2").sortable({
        group: 'ol.simple_with_animation',
        pullPlaceholder: false,

        onDragStart: function ($item, container, _super) {
            var offset = $item.offset(),
                pointer = container.rootGroup.pointer;

            adjustment = {
                left: pointer.left - offset.left,
                top: pointer.top - offset.top
            };

            _super($item, container);

        },
        onDrag: function ($item, position) {
            $item.css({
                left: position.left - adjustment.left,
                top: position.top - adjustment.top
            });
          //  alert('oink');
        },

        onDrop: function ($item, container, _super) {
            var $clonedItem = $('<li/>').css({ height: 0 });
            $item.before($clonedItem);
            $clonedItem.animate({ 'height': $item.height() });
          //  alert('wew');
            $item.animate($clonedItem.position(), function () {
                $clonedItem.detach();
                _super($item, container);
           //     alert('oink');
            });
         //   alert('oink');
        },

    });
    //alert('oink');
});
```

Comment: lol "oink" lol.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect to me. Hope it will help those who struggle too :)

```
    $("#container1, #container2").sortable(
        {
            group: 'ol.simple_with_animation',
            onDrop: function ($item, container, _super) {

                            var $clonedItem = $('<li/>').css({ height: 0 });
                            $item.before($clonedItem);
                            $clonedItem.animate({ 'height': $item.height() });

                            $item.animate($clonedItem.position(), function () {
                                $clonedItem.detach();
                                _super($item, container);

                            });
                            alert('oink');
                        }
        });
```